# VB.net inheritance, Member not found on only one call

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I'm at a loss on this one.  I have a class that inherits from "BaseClass".  BaseClass has a protected member called "UpdateData".

I have a class "DataAccess" that inherits from "UpdateData".  DataAccess has many different calls that use the "UpdateData" method.  This works just fine except for one single method on "DataAccess" that returns a "Member Not found" exception.

I've cleaned and rebuilt, and it's happening in Visual Studio as well as when deployed to the server.  The call to 'Add' works, but the call to 'Add Detail' is failing.

I've tried removing the transaction scopes listed below, tried using a factory pattern to get a new instance for each call, but neither has worked.  I'd rather not open the method up as "public" as we have hundreds of classes that use the protected "UpdateData" method just fine?

Any help, or new ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
''''On the base class
Protected Sub UpdateData(ByVal connString As String, ByVal procName As String, ByVal    ParamArray params As Object())
   UpdateDataWithTimeout(connString, procName, getTimeoutSetting, params)
End Sub

''''On the inherited class.  This one works
Protected Friend Overridable Sub Add(ByVal s1 As String, _
                        ByRef s2 As String, _
                        ByVal s3 As String, _
                        ByVal params As List(Of Object))

        Try

            params.Insert(0, s1)
            params.Insert(1, s2)
            params.Insert(2, s3)

            UpdateData(DB, SPI_PROC1, params.ToArray())

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub

''''On the inherited "DataAccess" class.  This one fails.
Protected Friend Overridable Sub AddDetail(ByVal ParamArray parms As Object())
    If Condition1 Then
            UpdateData(_sysConn, SPI_PROC, parms)
    End If
    End Sub

''''This is from a method in the class calling the "DataAccess" code
Dim da As DataAccess

da = New DataAccess(strVariable)

Using scope As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)

    ''''This call works just fine and can find "UpdateData"
    da.Add(string1, string2, string3, objectParameterList)

    'Separate database, so avoid MSDTC with new transaction scope
    Using scope2 As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew)
        ''''This call fails to find UpdateData
        da.AddDetail(string1, string5, string6, string7, string8, string3)

        scope2.Complete()
        scope.Complete()
    End Using

End Using
```

Addendum:  There is a difference in the IL here with one being "late binding" (which I need to stop) but am not sure how?

Failing method....

```
  IL_001f:  ldstr      "UpdateData"
  IL_0024:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0025:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Object
  IL_002a:  stloc.1
  IL_002b:  ldloc.1
  IL_002c:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_002d:  ldarg.0
  IL_002e:  ldfld      string DataAccess::_sysConn
  IL_0033:  stelem.ref
  IL_0034:  ldloc.1
  IL_0035:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0036:  ldloc.0
  IL_0037:  call       object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
  IL_003c:  stelem.ref
  IL_003d:  ldloc.1
  IL_003e:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_003f:  ldarg.1
  IL_0040:  stelem.ref
  IL_0041:  ldloc.1
  IL_0042:  stloc.2
  IL_0043:  ldloc.2
  IL_0044:  ldnull
  IL_0045:  ldnull
  IL_0046:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0047:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Boolean
  IL_004c:  stloc.3
  IL_004d:  ldloc.3
  IL_004e:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_004f:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0050:  stelem.i1
  IL_0051:  ldloc.3
  IL_0052:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0053:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0054:  stelem.i1
  IL_0055:  ldloc.3
  IL_0056:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0057:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0058:  stelem.i1
  IL_0059:  ldloc.3
  IL_005a:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_005b:  call       object [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding::LateCall(object,
                                                                                                                     class [mscorlib]System.Type,
                                                                                                                     string,
                                                                                                                     object[],
                                                                                                                     string[],
                                                                                                                     class [mscorlib]System.Type[],
                                                                                                                     bool[],
                                                                                                                     bool)
  IL_0060:  pop
  IL_0061:  ldloc.3
  IL_0062:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0063:  ldelem.i1
  IL_0064:  brfalse.s  IL_0088
  IL_0066:  ldarg.0
  IL_0067:  ldloc.2
  IL_0068:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0069:  ldelem.ref
  IL_006a:  call       object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
```

From the working method, here is the IL.

```
  IL_003b:  ldarg.0
  IL_003c:  ldstr      "conn"
  IL_0041:  ldstr      "proc"
  IL_0046:  ldarg.0
  IL_0047:  callvirt   instance string DataAccess::get_SYSCODE_SPAPPEND()
  IL_004c:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string,
                                                              string)
  IL_0051:  ldarg.s    params
  IL_0053:  callvirt   instance !0[] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<object>::ToArray()
  IL_0058:  callvirt   instance void [BaseClass]BaseClass::UpdateData(string,
                                                                                                                           string,
                                                                                                                           object[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the moment you ask the question the answer comes to you.

I altered my string variables for the SPI_PROC and SPI_PROC1 to be Private constants on the class rather than variables... set the _sysConn and DB in the class constructor and it switched everything to early binding.

So problem solved.  Hopefully this will save someone else a few hours of time.